# ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError - Association named 'whatever' was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, rails-engines

I have a complicated case where I'm developing a Rails 3 Engine and I only intermittently get the error in the title. Here's the stacktrace:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError - Association named 'whatever' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?:
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:150:in `block in records_by_reflection'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:146:in `records_by_reflection'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:139:in `grouped_records'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:130:in `preload_one'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:109:in `preload'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:98:in `block in run'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:98:in `run'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation.rb:181:in `block in exec_queries'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation.rb:180:in `exec_queries'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:39:in `+'
  /Users/me/src/appointment_engine/app/controllers/appointment_engine/appointments_controller.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in index'
  /Users/me/src/appointment_engine/app/controllers/appointment_engine/appointments_controller.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
  /Users/me/src/appointment_engine/app/controllers/appointment_engine/appointments_controller.rb:12:in `index'
```

To summarize: There's a model named `Appointment` in the engine which is polymorphically associated with `has_many :through` to the host app's `User` model (this is a requirement because we also associate to another model). Here's the `has_many` declaration in `Appointment`

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scheduleables,
    through: :appointments_scheduleables,
    source_type: KAE.scheduleable_class.name
  has_many :schedulers,
    through: :appointments_schedulers,
    source_type: KAE.scheduler_class.name
end
```

Here I ran into my first problem; I need to set the `:source_type` on `has_many :through` polymorphic associations (It doesn't work without it) and for that I need to know the class of the associated model but, when my engine's `Appointment` model loads it does so before the host app's `User` model loads and therefore my engine's module `KAE` hasn't received the value for `KAE.scheduleable_class` yet.

Here's how `KAE` receives that value:

```
# in host app
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_scheduler
end
```

I wrote `acts_as_scheduler` as an AR mixin, it will declare the `has_many :through` association to `Appointment`.

My first attempt to fix this: I put the `Appointment`'s `has_many` declaration in a hook inside a railtie:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :after_initialize do
  KAE::Appointment.class_eval do
    has_many :scheduleables,
      through: :appointments_scheduleables,
      source_type: KAE.scheduleable_class.name
    has_many :schedulers,
      through: :appointments_schedulers,
      source_type: KAE.scheduler_class.name
  end
end
```

Ok now that works, I wait till the host app loads completely and now I have the values for `KAE.scheduleable_class` and `KAE.scheduler_class`, great.

**Except I get the error in the title intermittently!**

I can boot up fine, use the app for a while (10-30 mins) and then out of nowhere boom! I've tried it under `rails server`, `thin`, and `unicorn`; all the same so it must be an app/framework level bug. I look in the active record preloader class to where the top of the stacktrace points to:

```
# lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:150
def records_by_reflection(association)
  records.group_by do |record|
    reflection = record.class.reflections[association]

    unless reflection
      raise ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError, "Association named '#{association}' was not found; " \
                                              "perhaps you misspelled it?"
    end

    reflection
  end
end
```

How can a model forget some of it's associations?

So now I'm doing this directly in the `Appointment` model and it seems to be working so far but it's really ugly:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  if KAE.scheduler_class && KAE.scheduleable_class
    has_many :scheduleables,
      through: :appointments_scheduleables,
      source_type: KAE.scheduleable_class.name
    has_many :schedulers,
      through: :appointments_schedulers,
      source_type: KAE.scheduler_class.name
  else
    binding.pry # TODO
    ActiveSupport.on_load :after_initialize do
      KAE::Appointment.class_eval do
        has_many :scheduleables,
          through: :appointments_scheduleables,
          source_type: KAE.scheduleable_class.name
        has_many :schedulers,
          through: :appointments_schedulers,
          source_type: KAE.scheduler_class.name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Anybody know of a better way of declaring `has_many :through` polymorphic associations in a Rails 3 Engine?**

I've been looking at open source projects like `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids` and `paper_trail` to see how they do their associations but they don't have polymorphic `has_many :through`.

**Anybody know any projects that have this type of association?**

Answer (score 0):

Load ordering can be a pain with Rails autoloading+auto-reloading magic. In these situations I just make my dependencies more explicit. I suggest you try using Rails's [`require_dependency`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency) in your host to ensure this doesn't occur:

```
# in host app
require_dependency 'appointment'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_scheduler
end
```

It's ActiveSupport's version of `require` that also plays well with the development environment's auto-reloading, which is probably why you're experiencing this issue intermittently when working on your application.

Comment: This had not occurred to me. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion :)